# Creating a custom GROK pattern

Tags: logstash, jira, logstash-grok, elk, atlassian-crowd

currently, I'm trying to create a grok pattern for this log

```
2020-03-11 05:54:26,174 JMXINSTRUMENTS-Threading [{"timestamp":"1583906066","label":"Threading","ObjectName":"java.lang:type\u003dThreading","attributes":[{"name":"CurrentThreadUserTime","value":18600000000},{"name":"ThreadCount","value":152},{"name":"TotalStartedThreadCount","value":1138},{"name":"CurrentThreadCpuTime","value":20804323112},{"name":"PeakThreadCount","value":164},{"name":"DaemonThreadCount","value":136}]}]
```

At the moment I can match correctly until the JMXINTRUMENTS-Threading by using this pattern:

```
%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp} (?<instrument>[^\ ]*) ?%{GREEDYDATA:log_message}
```

But I can not seem to match all the values after this. Has anybody got an idea as to what pattern I should use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i'm trying your pattern in https://grokdebug.herokuapp.com/ (which is the official debugger for logstash) and it does match everything after "JMXINTRUMENTS-Threading" with your pattern in a big field called log message, in this way:

```
{
  "timestamp": [
    [
      "2020-03-11 05:54:26,174"
    ]
  ],
  "YEAR": [
    [
      "2020"
    ]
  ],
  "MONTHNUM": [
    [
      "03"
    ]
  ],
  "MONTHDAY": [
    [
      "11"
    ]
  ],
  "HOUR": [
    [
      "05",
      null
    ]
  ],
  "MINUTE": [
    [
      "54",
      null
    ]
  ],
  "SECOND": [
    [
      "26,174"
    ]
  ],
  "ISO8601_TIMEZONE": [
    [
      null
    ]
  ],
  "instrument": [
    [
      "JMXINSTRUMENTS-Threading"
    ]
  ],
  "log_message": [
    [
      "[{"timestamp":"1583906066","label":"Threading","ObjectName":"java.lang:type\\u003dThreading","attributes":[{"name":"CurrentThreadUserTime","value":18600000000},{"name":"ThreadCount","value":152},{"name":"TotalStartedThreadCount","value":1138},{"name":"CurrentThreadCpuTime","value":20804323112},{"name":"PeakThreadCount","value":164},{"name":"DaemonThreadCount","value":136}]}]"
    ]
  ]
}
```

if you wish to match all the field contained in log message you should use a json filter in your logstash pipeline filter section, just right below your grok filter:

For example:

```
  grok {
     match => { "message" =>"%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp} (?<instrument>[^\ ]*) ?%{GREEDYDATA:log_message}" }
     tag_on_failure => ["no_match"]
  }
  if "no_match" not in [tags] {
    json {
      source => "log_message"
    }
  }
```

In that way your json will be splitted in key: value and parsed.

EDIT:

You could try to use a kv filter instead of json, here the docs: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-kv.html

```
grok {
     match => { "message" =>"%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp} (?<instrument>[^\ ]*) ?%{GREEDYDATA:log_message}" }
     tag_on_failure => ["no_match"]
  }
  if "no_match" not in [tags] {
    kv {
      source => "log_message"
      value_split => ":" 
      include_brackets => true #remove brackets
      remove_char_key => "\""
      remove_char_value => "\""
      field_split => ","
    }
  }
```

Comment: Currently, I'm getting a JSONparsefailure
    "log_message": "[{\"timestamp\":\"1584001526\",\"label\":\"Threading\",\"ObjectName\":\"java.lang:type\\u003dThreading\",\"attributes\":[{\"name\":\"CurrentThreadUserTime\",\"value\":22220000000},{\"name\":\"ThreadCount\",\"value\":152},{\"name\":\"TotalStartedThreadCount\",\"value\":1253},{\"name\":\"CurrentThreadCpuTime\",\"value\":24667871578},{\"name\":\"PeakThreadCount\",\"value\":164},{\"name\":\"DaemonThreadCount\",\"value\":136}]}]"

Comment: filter {
    if "atlassian-jira-perf" in [tags] {
    grok {
     match => { "message" =>"%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp} (?<instrument>[^\ ]*) ?%{GREEDYDATA:log_message}" }
     tag_on_failure => ["no_match"]
     add_tag => ["bananas"]
  }
  if "no_match" not in [tags] {
    json {
      source => "log_message"
    }
  }
}
}

Comment: I added an edit to my answer, anyway if you could share you entire error it would be better for debugging, it's really stange json filter is not working since that json is valid

Answer (score 1):

It worked for me after defining a different source and target in the JSON filter. Thanks for the help!

```
filter {
    if "atlassian-jira-perf" in [tags] {
    grok {
     match => { "message" =>"%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp} (?<instrument>[^\ ]*) ?%{GREEDYDATA:log_message_raw}" }
     tag_on_failure => ["no_match"]
     add_tag => ["bananas"]
  }
  if "no_match" not in [tags] {
    json {
      source => "log_message_raw"
      target => "parsed"
    }
  }
  mutate {    
        remove_field => ["message"]
    }
}
}
```